# NodeMCU 12E: Using 8 Digital pins 8 Channel Relay

Tags: relay, home-automation, nodemcu

I am trying to connect my 8 Channel Relay to my NodeMCU 12E and use it for automation with Alexa.

For digital output I am using the ports:
D0,D1,D2,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8

And for power:

Relay(VCC) -> Board Vin

Relay(GND) -> Board GND

This is being powered by a micro USB cable coming from my computer.

After uploading, the code works properly. 
When i disconnect and reconnect the power cable the code just doesn't work-unless i take out the GND and Vin wires before connecting the power cable and then plug both back in.

After online research I was recommended not to use D3, D4, D8, so how can I get 8 ports to connect to my relay?

Relay:
[image]

NodeMCU 12E:

[image]

Comment: You may well have joined the many who have built ESP8266 projects where their loads establish states of the bootstrap pins incompatible with the chip starting in the desired mode (ie, boot from external flash).  This can be rather tricky to get right - research the required pin states at boot and look at what things like pulling resistors, LEDs and bipolar transistor bases may be doing to pins in their initial undriven state when they are sampled as boot mode inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you are experiencing, is because the state of tgh GPIOs 0, 2, and 15 are in a state that stops the NodeMCU from booting. These GPIOs are on the NodeMCU pins D3, D4, and D8.

Just leave these pins free, and connect the relays to other pins.

This table might be useful:
https://iotbytes.wordpress.com/nodemcu-pinout/

Comment: Thanks the whole code works if I stop using D8 and use SD3 (GPIO10) instead

Comment: be careful with gpio10 if you use spiffs